# How does cancancan set the model instance, and how can I inspect it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, cancan, cancancan

I noticed users could access an action they shouldn't be able to access.

I [debugged](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/585e5ea54c900c6afd536f143cde962ccdf68607/docs/Debugging-Abilities.md#debugging-member-actions) in the rails console with something like

```rb
user = User.first 
physician = Physician.first 
ability = Ability.new(user)
ability.can?(:send_message, physician)
# => false
```

The above says that user **can't** access the send_message action for that physician, which is the desired behaviour, yet I know they can in the app!

I *think* this narrows down the cause to a problem with cancancan loading the wrong model instance for some reason. And that's hinted to in the cancan docs too:

> Note: this assumes that the model instance is being loaded properly.

But the problem is I'm not sure how to diagnose the problem from here, since the console says it should be working. I don't know how to view the model instance that cancancan has set, and I don't know what else to try.

Any ideas?

#### Update

I did manage to work around this by using `authorize! :send_message, physician` in the controller, **but** since I only stumbled upon this behaviour by chance, I think it's much more important to figure out why the wrong model instance was being loaded (especially so I can see if that was happening elsewhere too).

#### I figured out why it was probably happening (but I still don't know how to disagnose it)

I think this was happening because I had many custom actions, and some had `@physician = Physician.find(current_user.physician.id)` (i.e they're the current user), whereas others were more like `@physician = Physician.find_by_id(physician_params[:id])`. I'm not sure how cancan sets the instance model, but I do know it's not psychic, so it wouldn't know whether to set it to the current user's physician instance, or the physician instance for the physician id passed in.

#### What remains?

How does cancancan set the model instance for custom methods (I presume it tries something, and if that doesn't work, tries something else, etc etc)?

Small notes that help:

- `load_and_authorize_resource` *does* attempt to load the model instance for [non RESTful actions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65858725/5783745)
- Some useful info in the [docs](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/Authorizing-controller-actions.md#load_resource)
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59453259/5783745) may have something to do with what I experienced:

> When I returned slug it breaks this behaviour and I can edit all pokemons.

Answer (score 5):

Leaving my notes here in case they are helpful to anyone else.

TL;DR, there are a **lot** of nuanced assumptions cancancan makes, which you won't know about from the outset. I discovered many of them by thoroughly reading the comments in the cancancan [readme](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan), [code](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/585e5ea54c900c6afd536f143cde962ccdf68607/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb), and [defining abilities docs](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/Defining-Abilities.md)

So here goes..

#### How cancancan works

- if you call `authorize!` in the controller action itself, cancancan will look for an instance variable in each controller action.
- if you instead simply add `load_and_authorize_resource` at the start of your controller, that will [do two things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501730/5783745):

  1. Load an instance variable that cancancan ***thinks*** should be loaded, and
  2. Checks for authorization on that model instance
- Note that for custom actions, `load_and_authorize_resource` will still try to load a model instance, but how does it know what to load? It doesn't, it guesses, which, for me, I do not like, so be aware of that.

  - For me, I prefer to do the work of `load_and_authorize_resource` myself in two separate steps, so I know exactly what's going on.

    1. Ensure @article is generated via a before action for each controller action (or @articles for index action)
    2. Simply have a line at the top of the controller saying `load_and_authorize_resource` *after* the before action that sets the model instance

       - Note that the only difference is now the developer is responsible for loading the right model instance, and cancancan is not trying to guess it. I prefer this approach because it only takes one mistake to accidentally allow access where it shouldn't be granted.
- Also remember that `load_and_authorize_resource` should always go **after** any before actions that set the model instance variable

#### Random notes that may also help

- The name of the instance variable depends on the action. If we have an articles controller, then:

  - For the index action, authorize looks for @article**s**
  - For all other actions, authorize looks for @article

    - It then checks to see if the user is allowed access to that resource.
- `load_and_authorize_resource` checks to see if the model instance is set, and if not, it sets one. So if you have a before action that creates @article/@articles, then `load_and_authorize_resource` won't do it for you (i.e. it won't overwrite it), but if you didn't set one, cancan will try to set one. See [comments](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/585e5ea54c900c6afd536f143cde962ccdf68607/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb#L35-L47) from the source code:

> A resource is not loaded if the instance variable is already set. This makes it easy to override the behavior through a before_action on certain actions.

- An ability rule will override a previous one. (see [here](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/Ability-Precedence.md#ability-precedence) for an example)
- Just one last thing, never use `current_user` in ability.rb, it will error silently (!!), so be sure to use `user` instead :)

Comment: That's a nice explanation that clarified some things. Thanks for writing that, it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what is happening: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/585e5ea54c900c6afd536f143cde962ccdf68607/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb#L342-L355

```rb
    # Creates and returns the current user's ability and caches it. If you
    # want to override how the Ability is defined then this is the place.
    # Just define the method in the controller to change behavior.
    #
    #   def current_ability
    #     # instead of Ability.new(current_user)
    #     @current_ability ||= UserAbility.new(current_account)
    #   end
    #
    # Notice it is important to cache the ability object so it is not
    # recreated every time.
    def current_ability
      @current_ability ||= ::Ability.new(current_user)
    end
```